# Get class object from Java Interface

Tags: java, scala, interface, jna

I'm using a library with JNA. I've written a Java `Interface` of which I'm trying to get an instance:

```
object MyLibrary {
  val instance = Native.loadLibrary("libname", classOf[LibInterface]).asInstanceOf[LibInterface]
}
```

However, the scala compiler complains about not being able to find the MyLibrary object:

```
[error] ~/Workspace/project/src/package/Class.scala:28: not found: value MyLibrary
[error]     MyLibrary.method(param)
```

Strangely enough, the compilation of the `MyLibrary` `object` does not fail. I don't see a reason why the `MyLibrary` `object` should not be found...

Comment: show us Class.scala, probably import is missing or MyLibrary is in wrong package.

Answer (score 0):

After renaming the `MyLibrary` `object`, and fixing some imports, the issue is resolved. (Not sure why.) Once I get home this evening, I'll rename the file back to see whether it was really the imports that broke the compilation. (Which is strange because my IDE did not report any issues...)